# Is there a way to dynamically retrieve object methods and call them in python?

Tags: python

I would like to create a function like:

```
def test(x, way='a'):
    'a' = capitalize()
    'b' = lower()
    return x.way()
```

And where if I run:

```
test('ASD', way='b')
```

The ouput should be:

```
'asd'
```

Comment: why not just pass the function to `way` instead of using strings? i.e. `test(x, way=capitalize)`

Comment: I'd recommend Real Python as a good place to learn quickly. For example https://realpython.com/courses/python-conditional-statements/ and their Python Journey at https://realpython.com/start-here/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want, yes:

```
>>> method_map = dict(a='capitalize', b='lower')
>>> 
>>> def pick_method(text, method='a'):
...   return getattr(text, method_map[method])()
... 
>>> pick_method('UPPER', 'b')
'upper'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
def test(x, way='a'):
    if way == 'a':
        return x.upper()
    else:
        return x.lower()
```

## Edit:

Piggy-backing off of the post comment, you could also pass in a function as an argument (although at this point, you really might as well just call func(x) directly):

```
def test(x, func):
    return func(x)
```